# Снять выделение чекбоксов при нажатии кнопки назад

Tags: javascript, history

Как сделать обнуление чекбоксов при возвращении на страницу с ними, путем нажатия браузерной кнопки "Назад"?

Были попытки внедрения кода ниже, но это не помогло:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
  [...document.getElementsByClassName('form-check-input')].forEach(item =>{
    item.checked = false
  })
})
```

Как еще можно задать данное условие?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться эвентом [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event):

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", event => {
   const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-check-input")
   if (inputs) {
      inputs.forEach(input => { 
         input.setAttribute("checked", false) 
      })
   }
}, false)
```

Как альтернатива, можно снимать "выделения" в тот момент когда пользователь уходит со страницы, для этого замените эвент на [pagehide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event).